# Create a directory in Gitlab repo through web interface

Tags: git, version-control, github, gitlab

In a self-hosted GitLab installation, how can we create a new **directory** in a repository **through the web interface**?

In GitHub web interface, we can create a new directory by giving a filename like this:

```
/new-dir-name/new-file-name.md
```

..which will create a new directory named `new-dir-name/` and put the file `new-file-name.md` inside it.

But this is not working with GitLab **through the web interface**. How can we do this?

*(It's clear that we cannot create empty directories in a git repo.)*

Comment: In a twitter communication with GitLab, they replied that this cannot be done yet. - https://twitter.com/visrain/status/430987566955786240

Answer (score 2):

Not possible yet.

That is not an available feature as of now, but the development team is willing to include this functionality.
Check http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/5482948-create-directories-from-the-web-ui for more information

Comment: Yes, that request was made after a discussion on twitter - https://twitter.com/visrain/status/430987566955786240 Let's wait for this!

Answer (score 1):

> this is not working with GitLab. How can we do this?

Not through the web interface.

Workaround:

if you add *in your local clone* `new-dir-name/new-file-name.md`, commit and push, you will get a `new-dir-name` folder in your GitLab repo.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention "through web interface". It will work with local clone push for sure.

Comment: @VishnuHaridas I know. Not possible through the web interface. I have edited my answer to make that clearer, and to add a workaround.